# For every odd prime number $p \gt 3$ there exists another prime number $q \lt p$ such that $p - q = 2^n$ for some $n \geq 1$. Can you prove it?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

> **Conjecture.** Let $p$ be an odd prime number greater than $3$.  Then there exists another odd prime number $q \lt p$ such that $p - q = 2^n$ for some positive exponent $n$.

Can we prove this or is it another one of those simple to state, but almost impossible to prove, statements about prime numbers?

Comment: Where did you get this problem?

Comment: @Mike Thanks. I got it trying to prove Twin primes.  It's certainly related.  It doesn't immediately give twin primes though.

Comment: There are probably infinite many counterexamples.

Comment: You might find Polignac's conjecture interesting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be false, with $127$ being the least counterexample.

Comment: I believe there are $1245$ counterexamples less than $100000$ with the greatest of these being $99929$.